# How can I use variables from app.post in another app.post using node js express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to use the variables that I defined as const in app.post so when the user is submitting an input in the form I will receive it and store it.
but when I try to send the variables again to the user in order to let the user check the full information in app.post it shows the the variable is not defined.

what am I missing here? please see my code below

```
app.get('/',function(request,response){
  response.sendFile(__dirname+"/CreatingService.html")
  })
});

  app.post('/CreatingService', (req, res) =>{

    const RecID = req.body.arg1;
    const assetno = req.body.arg2;
    const space = req.body.arg3;
    const pdate = req.body.arg4;
    const dist = req.body.arg5;
    const state = req.body.arg6;
    const status = req.body.arg7;
    const first = req.body.arg8;
    const middle = req.body.arg9;
    const last = req.body.arg10;
    const id = req.body.arg11;

   /*....some code.....*/
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/desktop2-24.html");

    })
```

I'm getting the response in the vs console like this

```
{
  flg: 0,
  st: 200,
  data: {
    response: {
      RecID: '888',
      AssetNo: 1234,
      AssetSpace: 1000,
      AssetDate: '8/8',
      AssetDist: 'narjes',
      AssetState: 'altaeawun',
      AssetStatus: 'valid',
      F_owner: 'bushra',
      M_owner: 'mohammed',
      L_owner: 'almansour',
      OwnerID: '******1010'
    }
  }
}
```

and this app.post I use to send the data back to the user

```
   app.post('/desktop2-24', (req, res1) =>{
 const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res3));
                res1.render("readAsset",{assetno: obj.data.response.AssetNo })
                
    /*...some code...*/
                        })
              .catch (err =>{
                console.log(err)
              })
      
          })
          
    
        })
  app.listen(3000);
```

and this is my ejs file to send data

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <meta charsey="utf-8">
        <title> Read deed info</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>assetno: <%= assetno %></p>
        </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not sure whether this can work. It seems to rely on a variable `obj`, where is that declared? You cannot use global variables with express, because they would be seen by all concurrent requests (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/74582772/16462950).

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I forgot to copy this line in my code  const obj = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res3));

Comment: Where is `res3` declared?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen in the second app.post, my code is a bit complex... so I didn't copy it all but I think it is because that I can not use global variables like you said ...

Answer (score 0):

so basically all I had to do is to defined the the variables with an empty value in the second app.post